# ASP.NET Core, Validating a numeric password

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Let's say I have a numeric password field, essentially a PIN:

```
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public int Password { get; set; }
```

and then attempt to submit an alphabetic password, then the validation will fail on the server (as expected), but displays `The value 'foo' is not valid for Password.` to the user.

Is there any way to avoid displaying the attempted password?  Or am I thinking about this wrong?

I could just make the field a string and validate it otherwise, but I'm not sure I like that solution, and was hoping there was something else I'm overlooking.

Comment: `I could just make the field a string and validate it ` <-- i like it. Could you elaborate why you don't? to me it seems the in built data valiation doesnt do *exactly* what you want so you have to code something yourself - perfectly acceptable. Also given the password *is not* acceptable what is your issue with displaying it?

Comment: have you tried catching and handle the exception?

Comment: I would always take user Input as strings. If it need to be a Integer in the backend, you can parse it then.
btb, only picking Numeric Characters as valid PW Characters means that it would be a heck of a lot easier to brute-force that PW anyway.

Comment: @wal `so you have to code something yourself` You're right, I'm just being stupid, but my issue with it wasn't not wanting to write it myself, rather that I was caught up on the fact that it's a number so it "should" be modeled as an int.

Comment: What about specifying an ErrorMessage with your data type attribute? `[DataType(DataType.Password, ErrorMessage = "Not a valid password")]`

Comment: @AdamT thats probably the best solution :) Perhaps insert a bit more info such as 'must be numeric only'

Comment: Ok now I know I'm just being really dumb, but I can't quite get @AdamT's to work.  As far as I see it, the validation error isn't on the DataType attribute.

Comment: Can you provide some more of your server side code please? I believe you may be best going with an alternative approach here. Having Password as type `int` will cause issues whenever a user attempts to submit anything other than an int.

Comment: I'd be careful with making a PIN code an integer though. If someone sends '0123' or '123', it is interpreted the same on the server, because the leading zero doesn't matter in the number realm. It certainly does in the Pin code realm though. Therefore, use a string instead.

Comment: @JssDWt Thanks, I hadn't actually thought of that -.-  I had already gone ahead and made it a string anyways, but now I feel silly for not considering that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have a custom error message when using the `DataType` attribute.

```
[DataType(DataType.Password, ErrorMessage = "Your password must be a integer.")]
```

See documentation on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples).

As others have mentioned in the comments though, using an `int` may not be the best approach here.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this to work, however.  The error message isn't affected, as validation error isn't on the DataType attribute